# Ruby eval behaves differently in irb versus in a file

Tags: ruby, eval

This code works in irb:

```
irb(main):037:0> eval <<-EOS
irb(main):038:0" #{attribute} = "host"
irb(main):039:0" puts machine
irb(main):040:0" EOS
host
=> nil
irb(main):041:0> puts machine
host
=> nil
irb(main):042:0> puts attribute
machine
=> nil
irb(main):043:0>
```

however when I try to execute the same code as a ruby script I get the following error:

```
../autosys/convert_jil_to_zapp.rb:40: undefined local variable or method `machine' for main:Object (NameError)
        from ../autosys/convert_jil_to_zapp.rb:29:in `each_line'
        from ../autosys/convert_jil_to_zapp.rb:29
        from ../autosys/convert_jil_to_zapp.rb:27:in `each'
        from ../autosys/convert_jil_to_zapp.rb:27
pi929c1n10 /ms/user/h/hirscst/ruby/autosys 77$ gvim try.rb
pi929c1n10 /ms/user/h/hirscst/ruby/autosys 78$ chmod +x try.rb
pi929c1n10 /ms/user/h/hirscst/ruby/autosys 79$ ./try.rb
host
./try.rb:8: undefined local variable or method `machine' for main:Object (NameError)
```

can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because the `machine` variable was not already defined when `eval` was run.  A more concise example:

#### Works in IRB but not as a script

```
eval 'x = 3'
puts x # throws an exception when run as a script
=> 3
```

#### Works in IRB and as a script

```
x = 1
eval 'x = 3'
puts x
=> 3
```

To [quote Matz](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/a954f8aaf698a0b9/e1c761b71b63b82e?#422ad5daee216181):

> local variables should be determined at compile time, thus local 
>   variables defined first in the eval'ed string, can only be accessed from 
>   other eval'ed strings.  In addition, they will be more ephemeral in 
>   Ruby2, so that these variables will not be accessed from outside.

The difference is that in IRB *everything* is being eval'd, so it's all in the same scope.  That is, you're essentially doing this in IRB:

```
eval 'x = 3'
eval 'puts x'
```

Which works both in IRB and as a script.

Comment: I did not know that eval operates in a lower scope. But does defining x in the main script body causes the variables to be passed to eval by reference?

Comment: Yes, it seems to behave a lot like this: `1.times {a = 3}; puts a; # NameError: undefined local variable or method 'a' for main:Object` versus `a = 1; 1.times {a = 3}; puts a; # 3` Judging by the linked thread, Matz made it work this way out of convenience of implementation.

Comment: So, how does one meta-program new variables names, that weill be OUTSIDE the meta-programmed read part (no globals)? Isn't Ruby the language of making the impossible possible, and with elegance?

Comment: Maybe the behavior changed, now my irb 0.9.6 on ruby 2.2.6 no longer runs the "Works in IRB" example

Answer (score 0):

Because you're defining a method or variable named `machine` in IRB but not in your Ruby script.