# Ruby 1.9.3 define var with eval

Tags: ruby, variables, eval

I am writing something like REPL in Ruby and I need to define vars on the run.
I figured it out that I should use eval, but here is excerpt from irb session to test it.
In 1.9.3 (That would work in 1.8)

```
> eval 'a = 3'
=> 3
> a
=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object
```

They changed it in 1.9 to:

```
> eval 'a = 3'
=> 3 
> eval 'a'
=> 3
```

So seems like changed it since 1.9. How can I define vars in 1.9.3 using eval (or something similar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IRB is lying to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/715159/17875).  This as a *script*:

```
eval 'a = 3'
puts a
```

fails the same way under 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 for me.

Unfortunately the equivalent mentioned both by you and in that answer,

```
eval 'a = 3'
eval 'puts a'
```

still doesn't work in 1.9 as a script, though it does work in 1.8.

This, however, works for me in both:

```
b = binding
b.eval 'a = 3'
b.eval 'puts a'
```

Using the same [binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Binding.html) means variable assignments all happen in the same context.  You won't be able to read them from the outside since locals are bound at compile-time, but if you're writing a REPL, "compile-time" is just "when I get another line and eval it" which is fine.

Comment: Its not exactly true that you can't read the variables from outside of the context.  The following will work: a = b.eval('a')

Comment: @KennethBaltrinic i wouldn't really call that "reading from outside"; you're just asking the context to read it for you  :)