# results of eval when used to define variables not seen in later lines

Tags: ruby, eval

I am trying to assign a variable within `eval`, and then print it out. The code is:

```
eval "foo=nil"
puts foo
```

What I get is:

> undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object (NameError)

When I use `puts` within the `eval`, I get no errors. This means that `foo` is scoped within the `eval`. How can I get it to be outside the `eval` scope, yet not as a global variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715010/ruby-eval-behaves-differently-in-irb-versus-in-a-file/715159#715159

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404198/ruby-1-9-3-define-var-with-eval

Comment: You can't, see [How to dynamically create a local variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552891/how-to-dynamically-create-a-local-variable)

Comment: @Stefan I think you once had an answer to this question using a binding object. I cannot find the question immediately.

Comment: @sawa that was about creating local variables in IRB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842765/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-local-variable-in-ruby

Comment: `foo` is not global variable. `$foo` is global variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think foo is going out of scope in your eval.

if you declare it before your eval it will work ok.  Eg;

```
foo='foo'
eval "foo=nil"
puts foo.to_s
```

output:

```
=> nil
```